# React Context API functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a WordSearch Game. So i am declaring an array of some words in  Context provider and passing it to its child components. I am getting the words.
But in child components, i have component of keyboard, where in click of that alphabet button the value should be passed to a another child component which will check the word is correct or wrong.

So my question is how can i send values from a child component to another child component.

```js
//this is word provider

  

  import React, { createContext, useState} from 'react'

    export const WordContext = createContext();

    export  const WordProvider =props =>{
        const hangmanWords = [
            "apple",
            "ant",
            "ball",
            "bat",
            "car",
            "cat",
            "dog",
            "elephant"
        ];
        return(
           <WordContext.Provider value={[hangmanWords]}>
              {props.children}
           </WordContext.Provider>
        );
    };  

    //from here i need to send it to another child component
    import React, {useState,useContext} from "react";
    import {Card ,CardBody, Container,CardTitle,Button} from 'reactstrap';
    import {WordContext} from "../Context/WordContext"
    import "../App.css"
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

    const Alphabets = () => {
     
      const [alphabets] = useState(['A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'])

      const showValue =(alphabet)=>{
        console.log(alphabet)
      }
     

        return(
          
            <Container className="p-5">
              <Card color="warning" >
                     <CardBody>
                       <CardTitle style={{"font-weight" : "bold", "font-size":"30px"}}>All Alphabets</CardTitle>
                       <div className="grid">
                          {alphabets.map((alphabet)=>(
                              <div style={{"flex-direction" :'row'}}  className="box " >
                                <Button color="primary" onClick={() => showValue(alphabet)}>  
                               
                                    {alphabet}  
                                                           
                                 </Button>
                              </div>
                            ))}                    
                       </div>
                     </CardBody>
               </Card>
            </Container>      
        )

    }

    export default Alphabets;

//here inside the input value i need to display the letter
import React, {useState,useContext} from "react";
import {Card ,CardBody, Container,CardTitle,Input,Button} from 'reactstrap';
import {WordContext} from "../Context/WordContext"


const Correct = () => {
  const [hangmanWords] = useContext(WordContext)
  const [pickedCorrect, setPickedCorrect] = useState([])

  const updateCorrect= e =>{
       setPickedCorrect(e.target.value)
  }
  const checkCorrect = ()=>{

    {hangmanWords.map(word=> 
      {
        if(pickedCorrect === word){
          console.log("correct word")
        }
      }
    )}
  
  }
    return(
        <Container className="p-5">
          <Card color="success">
            <CardBody>
              <CardTitle style={{"font-weight" : "bold", "font-size":"30px"}}>Picked Correct</CardTitle>
              <Input type="text"
              value={pickedCorrect} 
              onChange={updateCorrect}>           
              </Input>
              <Button onClick={checkCorrect}>
                 Submit
              </Button>
            </CardBody>
           </Card>
        </Container>
     
        
    )

}

export default Correct;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need `Context` here. All you need is `props`. You may have words in top `App` component together with state of chosen value from `Alphabet`. And then pass this data to child components

So, you need:

1. Define state on parent component
2. Pass handler `onPick` to `Alphabet` which will set chosen value to state
3. Invoke `onPick` in `Alphabet` on click with the chosen value
4. Pass chosen value from to another child component.

So, basically flow could be described like "Data down, actions up".
Here's good article on this https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Upto point 3 u mentioned i have done it. I am getting the value also. Now how to send it from alphabets component to correct component.

Answer (score 0):

first of i might say that instead of this:

```
<WordContext.Provider value={[hangmanWords]}>
```

you can do this :

```
<WordContext.Provider value={{hangmanWords}}>
```

you can pass the object to the value of context and it will make you to pass another values like the `alphabet` variable by taking it inside of the context like below:

```
export  const WordProvider =props =>{
        const hangmanWords = [
            "apple",
            "ant",
            "ball",
            "bat",
            "car",
            "cat",
            "dog",
            "elephant"
        ];

        const alphabets =['A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']


        return(
           <WordContext.Provider value={{hangmanWords, alphabets}}>
              {props.children}
           </WordContext.Provider>
        );
    };
```

now in every component that you want to access the `alphabet` and the `hangmanWords`, you can get it from your context.

### another Tip:

if you want to have to keep track of which letter is been selected from input, you need to have to pass a handler function inside of the context value Object and a state for keep tracking it also, and get access for the handler and the state of the selected input from every where that you consume the context value!

Comment: Yes i want to keep track of selected letter. That is where I am having the difficulty actually. Like how to consume the value from child component that is in my case alphabets and how to send it to the correct and wrong component.